# simple_form hints as tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm trying to have my `simple_form` hints appear as twitter-bootstrap tooltips, so that the hint only appears when the user selects the input field or hovers on it.

The form item would look like (in haml):

```
:ruby 
  title = <<TITLE
    This text is normally hidden and pops up as a bootstrap tooltip 
    only when the user hovers on the input field.
  TITLE
= f.input :opt_out, hint: title
```

My CSS and Javascript for the hint of simple_form are vanilla, so I think I have to modify the `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` initializer file:

```
b.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :hint }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this way:

```
    :ruby 
      title = <<TIT 
        This text is normally hidden and pops up as a bootstrap tooltip 
only when the user hovers on the input field.
      TIT
      link = link_to "what's this?", "", rel: "tooltip", title: title, data: {placement: "right"}
      label = "Opt out #{link}"
    = f.input :opt_out, label: raw(label)
```